# How to access values from the constructor in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a react component `maintoolbar.tsx` that has a grid object passed to it as a prop

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from '../grid';

interface PropsInterface {
  grid: Grid;
}

const MainToolbar: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
  const { grid } = props;
  const test = grid.mainToolbar.shapes[0].name;
//                                       ^ doesnt return the name
  const newNode = () => {
    grid.newNode();
  };

  return (
    <div className='main-toolbar'>
     ...
    </div>
  );
};

export { MainToolbar };
```

This is what I get returned, but how to do I access the value of this.name??

```
class Square {
  constructor(nodes) {
    this.name = 'square';
```

The grid object I'm getting from the props has an array of objects

```
import { Square } from './components/square';
class Grid {
  constructor() {
    this.mainToolbar = {
      shapes: [Square],
    };
  }
}
export { Grid };
```

And finally square

```
class Square {
  name: string;

  constructor(nodes: NodesInterface) {
    this.name = 'square';
  }
}

export { Square };
```

if a do   `console.log(grid.mainToolbar.shapes);`
i get this [f] thing ive not seen before

[image]

If I do `console.log(grid.mainToolbar.shapes[0], ' type ' , typeof grid.mainToolbar.shapes[0]);` i get

[image]

UPDATE

Adding

```
interface MainToolbarInterface {
  [key: string]: any;
}
class Grid
  mainToolbar: MainToolbarInterface;

  constructor() {
    this.mainToolbar = {
      shapes: [new Square(this)],
    };
  }
```

gives me the name, obviously any is not right, what shoujld it be?

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(grid.mainToolbar.shapes)` just above `  const test = grid.mainToolbar.shapes[0].name;`

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I have updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: You need `new Square()` You have just put the class definition in the array

Comment: How would I express this? `console.log(new grid.mainToolbar.shapes[0].name);` ??

Comment: Just to check something. Try reverting that change and add.`console.log(grid.mainToolbar.shapes[0], ' type ' , typeof grid.mainToolbar.shapes[0]);`

Comment: If that still doesn't work. Can you show where `MainToolbar` is getting instantiated? where is main toolbar getting its props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Grid` constructor. You have

```js
constructor() {
  this.mainToolbar = {
    shapes: [Square],
  };
}
```

This is making `shapes` = an array with the `Square` class as its first element.

Try

```js
constructor() {
  this.mainToolbar = {
    shapes: [new Square()],
  };
}
```

If you were not wanting to initialize it there, and this was the type definition. Then instead

```js
constructor() {
  this.mainToolbar = {
    shapes: [],
  }: {
    shape: Square[]
  };
}
```

---

After update. For the interface type.

```js
interface MainToolbarInterface {
  shapes: Array<Square>;
}

class Grid
mainToolbar: MainToolbarInterface;

constructor() {
  this.mainToolbar = {
    shapes: [new Square(this)],
  };
}
```

or `shapes: Square[];` if you prefer.

Comment: I now get `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)` when i do  `console.log(grid.mainToolbar.shapes[0].name );`

Comment: try `constructor() {
  this.mainToolbar = {
    shapes: [new Shape()],
  }: {
    shape: Square[]
  };
}`? What do the console.logs give withought .name on the end